# Redux updating the wrong state, setting previously set state to null

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have two redux state variables, one that hold an array of user information and one that holds a true/false value for a side drawer open/close feature. The true/false value triggers a className change which triggers CSS to open/close the drawer. The array of user information is fetched from a firebase cloud firestore database collection.

For some reason after the user array is fetched and saved to the redux state and a user opens the side drawer the redux action sent is only for the side drawer, but the side drawer and users information is changed.

The side drawer opens like normal, but the user array is set to null.

Redux Events:

1. Initial State: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeFrx.jpg
2. After side drawer is opened: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipA4o.jpg
3. Side Drawer Event Difference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aiui.jpg

Side Drawer Component

```
class SideDrawer extends Component {

    render() {
        let drawerClasses = ['side-drawer'];
        if (this.props.toggled) {
            drawerClasses = ['side-drawer', 'open'];
        }



        return (
                <div className={drawerClasses.join(' ')} >
                    <div className="side-drawer-container" >
                        <div className="router-login-button" onClick={this.props.toggleSideDrawer} >
                            <OktaAuthButton />
                        </div>
                        <div className="side-drawer-link" onClick={this.props.toggleSideDrawer} >
                            <Link to="/" >Map</Link>
                        </div>
                        <div className="side-drawer-link" onClick={this.props.toggleSideDrawer} >
                            <Users />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        )

    }

}

const mapStateToProps = ({ sideDrawer }) => ({
    toggled: sideDrawer.toggled,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        toggleSideDrawer: () => dispatch({ type: TOGGLE_SIDEDRAWER, payload: true })
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SideDrawer);
```

Side Drawer Reducer

```
import { TOGGLE_SIDEDRAWER } from './actions';

const initialState = {
    toggled: false
};

export default function sideDrawerReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case TOGGLE_SIDEDRAWER:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                toggled: action.payload
            });
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Users Component

```
class Users extends Component {
    /* commented code not needed to be shown */

    componentDidMount() {
        initializeFirebaseApp();

        // Get user list from firestore 'users' collection
        this.loadUsers();
    }

    async loadUsers() {
        getAllUsers().then((users) => {
            this.props.setUsers(users);
        });
    }


    render() {
        if(this.props.users != null) {
            var users = this.props.users.map((el, i) => (
                <li key={el.id} className='user' onClick={this.props.toggleSideDrawer}><Link to={"/user/" + el.id}>{el.firstname}</Link></li>
            ));
            console.log(users);
        }

        console.log(this.props.users);

        return (
            <div className="user-container">
                {users}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ users }) => ({
    users: users.friends
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        setUsers: (users) => dispatch({type: SET_FRIENDS, payload: users}),
        toggleSideDrawer: () => dispatch({ type: TOGGLE_SIDEDRAWER, payload: false })
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Users);
```

Users Reducer

```
import { SET_FRIENDS } from './actions';

const initialState = {
    friends: null,
    groups: null
};

export default function userReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case SET_FRIENDS:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                friends: action.payload
            });
        default:
            return initialState;
    }
}
```

I expect the side drawer to open and render the list of users in the drawer under the "Login" and "Map" Links

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default case for `userReducer` is returning `initialState` instead of `state` so every action through the redux store that is not `SET_FRIENDS` (e.g. `TOGGLE_SIDEDRAWER`) will reset the `userReducer` to `initialState` where `users` is `null`. Return `state` instead and you should be good to go.

```
export default function userReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case SET_FRIENDS:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                friends: action.payload
            });
        // Change to `return state;`
        default:
            return initialState;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome fix. Thank you, this was exactly what I was missing.